# UML Class Diagram HashMap Data Type

Tags: java, c#, uml, class-diagram

How can I show a Java HashMap data type in UML Class Diagram (or C# dictionary)?

I.E. This class:

```
public class Test
{
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private Map<String, int> map1;    
    public Test(){
        this.map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.map1 = new HashMap<String, int>();
    }    
    public getMap(){
        return this.map;
    }    
    public addToMap(String key, String value){
        this.map.put(key,value);
    }    
    public getMap1(){
        return this.map1;
    }    
    public addToMap1(String key, int value){
        this.map1.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

If possible please provide an example with UML Class Diagram.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What concrete problem did you encounter when drawing this diagram? Please [edit] the question with more details if you'd like to get help.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689672/how-to-represent-a-net-dictionary-type-in-uml

Answer (score 1):

You would show it the same way as you would do with any other data type.

[image]

(Generated in IntelliJ)

Comment: Ok, but doesn't it depend on the focus ?  If it's about the internal design of that class, wouldn't you perhaps consider whether or not to show the private composition for the maps,  and [the binding dependency to the templated classes](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html#template-binding) ?

Comment: It would definitely depend on the focus but in my opinion if you are creating a typical class diagram you wouldn't dig deeper in the underlying implementations of common data types.